# My unordered list is rendered from a json file but I want a border around each list element

Tags: javascript, css, reactjs, list

My list elements are not formatted. I want a border around each element.

I have tried this:

```
.list{
    border: 1px solid black;
}
```

for this

```
 return (
        <ul className="col-md-6 list-group">
        <li class="ywList">
        { Items}
        </li>
        </ul>
```

The rendered list should display with a border around each element so that each list element lines up in a box as the same size.

Comment: className not class on the list item element.

Comment: _"I want a border **around each** element."_ - Right now you're having on `<li>` for all `Items`

Comment: None of these suggestions worked.

Answer (score 1):

As mentioned in the comments, you should replace 'class' for 'className' and loop trough your items to render them as list elements.

```
return (
  <ul className="col-md-6 list-group">
      {
         Items.map(item => (
              // Here
              <li className="orderedList">
                  {item}
              </li>
         ))
      }
  </ul>
);
```

This only works if Items variable is an array.

Edit: I looked into your sandbox an notice two things:

1. Your css wasn't loading
2. Your Items are already list items tags

In order to get the desired effect I just add a className prop to your PostItem component, it looks like this:

PostItem.js

```
// Here we check the className prop
<li className={`list-group-item ${props.className || ''}`}>
 ...
</li>
```

The new component will now has a className prop

NewList.js

```
const NewList = props => {
  const NewListItems = props.ambers.map(amber => {
    return (
      <PostItem
        // Here we add a className
        className="orderedList"
        key={amber.data.created}
        post={amber.data}
      />
    );
  });

  return <ul className="col-md-6 list-group">{NewListItems}</ul>;
};
```

Comment: I will edit my answer to explain what you need https://codesandbox.io/s/suspicious-currying-fs9wu

Comment: Is it possible that the link title be placed on the side of the thumbnail?

Comment: I updated the sandbox, you just need to create some css: .post-list-media {
  display: flex;
}
.post-list-media > div {
  flex: 1;
}

Comment: Figured it out! :)

Comment: Great! I was away from my computer couldn't edit the file!